Requiero comparar los datos de un mismo campo en una tabla para ver que cambios se hicieron
Buenos dias por favor si me pueden ayudar con la siguiente consulta para DB Mysql, no tengo mucha experiencia con MySql
La estructura de mi tabla es:



id
usuario
Fecha
hora
campo1
campo2
obs.
estado




1
A
23/04/2024
15:13:20
151318-7519
1910112823
1
MODIFICADO


2
A
23/04/2024
15:19:15
151318-7519
1910112823
12
MODIFICADO


3
A
23/04/2024
15:20:39
151318-7519
1910112823
13
MODIFICADO


4
A
23/04/2024
15:31:25
151318-7519
1910112823
16
ACTIVO



El registro Id=1 inicialmente tenia el campo “ESTADO”=ACTIVO y asi los demas registros del ejemplo.
El usuario invoca un registro de la tabla, hace modificaciones a los campos, a uno o varios en este caso al campo OBSERVACIONES y al hacer el sumit de la transacción, lo que hace la rutina es insertar un nuevo registro en la misma tabla, con las modificaciones realizadas y le asigna el valor de ACTIVO al campo “ESTADO” y al registro viejo el valor de MODIFICADO al campo “ESTADO”.
En el ejempo de la tabla se hicieron 4 modificaciones
La siguiente vez que se requiera otra modificación el sistema jala el ultimo registro insertado con ESTADO=ACTIVO y se repite la rutina.
Requiero hacer un query que me compare los campos que han sido modificados en el tiempo, en este caso OBSERVACIONES, y pueden ser mas campos y solo me muestre los campos que han sido modificados. En el caso de ejempo especifico deberia mostrarme los valores 1, 12 y 13
Intento de query sobre la misma tabla
SELECT t1.id, t1.observaciones, t2.observaciones FROM datos_informe_conclusiones t1 INNER JOIN datos_informe_conclusiones t2 ON t1.id<>t2.id WHERE t1.observaciones<>t2.observaciones and t1.CODIGO_REG like 'REG23042024 151249837';

Este query me vota la comparación con todos los registros de la tabla 28K

Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Si queres traer todos los registros modificados, y el ID no es el mismo, debe haber uno o varios campos que permitan relacionar un registro con sus modificaciones. Sugiero que incluyas esa información en la pregunta.

No acabo de entender exactamente qué formato quieres de salida. Una o varias columnas? Tantos registros como modificaciones? Si hay varios campos modificados qué aparece en cada fila de la salida?

Eso que indicas parece un registro de auditoria... no seria mejor, tener un registro de auditoria???

Quieres ver todos los valores viejos de los campos que se han cambiado. Por eso compara los registros viejos con el registro actual y usa GROUP_CONCAT para mostrar una lista de valores viejos para cada columna:
select
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN NOT old.campo1 <=> new.campo1 THEN old.campo1 END ORDER BY old.campo1 SEPARATOR ', ') AS old_campo1,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN NOT old.campo2 <=> new.campo2 THEN old.campo2 END ORDER BY old.campo2 SEPARATOR ', ') AS old_campo2,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN NOT old.obs    <=> new.obs    THEN old.obs    END ORDER BY old.obs    SEPARATOR ', ') AS old_obs
from mytable old
cross join mytable new
where old.estado = 'MODIFICADO'
and new.estado = 'ACTIVO';

Demostración: https://dbfiddle.uk/omjwV9Fc

Muchas gracias por la respuesta, voy a probar y te comento como me va..

Buenas tardes hice algunas pruebas y todas salieron satisfactorias, queria agradecer a la persona que me envio la respuesta con la rutina exacta a lo requerido, Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!  Lamentablemente no me sale el nobre de quien me ayudó.. :(
